# Debug error: stack around the variable 'cardDesc' was corrupted

Tags: c++, pointers, stack

TITLE.
The function i'm using is this:

```
void GetVideoCardInfo(int* memoryVar, char* cardName)
{
    strcpy_s(cardName, 128, m_videoCardDescription);
    *memoryVar = m_videoCardMemory;
    return;
}
```

m_videoCardDescription is a '128 character long' character array that has the description of my video card in it. Here is where I am calling the function:

```
bool writeGPUnameDesc() {
    char cardDesc;
    int cardMem;
    m_D3D->GetVideoCardInfo(&cardMem, &cardDesc);

    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("gpuNameAndDesc.txt");
    myfile << "Graphics card name: " << cardDesc;
    myfile << " - Graphics card memory: " << cardMem;
    myfile.close();

    return true;
}
```

When I run the program a message box pops up that says Runtime-check failure #2
and the title. If anyone can help thanks in advance.

Comment: `cardDesc` has room for exactly one character. You read 128 characters into that and you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: Is there a way I can make it able to store 128 characters but still work as a pointer?

Comment: How about `char cardDesc[128];` ....

Comment: Why are you messing with C-style strings in C++? What's the problem with `std::string`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are copying 128 characters into `char cardDesc`, which represents only 1 character.

You should change the type of `cardDesc` to a char-array:

```
char cardDesc[128];
// ...
m_D3D->GetVideoCardInfo(&cardMem, cardDesc);
//                                ^ no &
```

Comment: Where does the null terminator go?

Comment: @user4581301 inside `cardDesc`, according to the documentation of `strcpy_s`

Comment: Can't argue that. What I'm worried about is is the originator 128 characters plus terminator or 128 including terminator. Could be dropping a character.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

```
std::string GetVideoCardInfo(int & memoryVar)
{
    memoryVar = m_videoCardMemory;
    return m_videoCardDescription;;
}


bool writeGPUnameDesc() {
    int cardMem;
    std::string cardDesc = m_D3D->GetVideoCardInfo(cardMem); 

    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("gpuNameAndDesc.txt");
    myfile << "Graphics card name: " << cardDesc;
    myfile << " - Graphics card memory: " << cardMem;
    myfile.close();

    return true;
}
```

## Explanation

```
strcpy_s(cardName, 128, m_videoCardDescription);
```

is a blatant lie. The size of `cardName` is exactly one character. If you lie to `strcpy_s` its extra checking to make sure you don't overrun the buffer cannot help you.

## Inferior solutions

Replace

```
char cardDesc;
```

with

```
char cardDesc[129];
```

The better approach gets rid of the [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad) entirely.

Up near the top of the file

```
namespace // annonymous namespace. Contents will not leak out of the file
{
    constexpr int MAX_CARD_NAME_LENGTH = 129 // 128 plus room for nul terminator
}
```

and then

```
void GetVideoCardInfo(int* memoryVar, char* cardName)
{
    strcpy_s(cardName, MAX_CARD_NAME_LENGTH, m_videoCardDescription);
    *memoryVar = m_videoCardMemory;
    return;
}
```

and

```
bool writeGPUnameDesc() {
    char cardDesc[MAX_CARD_NAME_LENGTH]; // now an array
    int cardMem;
    m_D3D->GetVideoCardInfo(&cardMem, cardDesc); // don't need to take address of array

    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("gpuNameAndDesc.txt");
    myfile << "Graphics card name: " << cardDesc;
    myfile << " - Graphics card memory: " << cardMem;
    myfile.close();

    return true;
}
```